# c# can predefined values sum up to a certain value

Tags: c#, math

I have a list with predefined int values.

```
List<int> values = new List<int>() { 1, 5, 7, 12, 20 };
```

I would like to know if a certain value can be summed up by the values in my list.

```
public bool canBeSummed(int value)
{
//Can any of the values in values sum up to value?
}
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: And where's your attempt?

Comment: can the values be reused or only once?

Comment: Can you please provide sample input/output of what you expect?

Comment: 6 would be true since 1+ 5 = 6;
37 would be true since 20 + 12 + 5;
9 would be false since no values can make 9;

Comment: @PablonotPicasso he expects 18 to return `true` (`12 + 1 + 5`) = 18, but `3` to return `false`, since no comination of the values adds up to 3

Comment: If the values can be reeused, the answer is always yes.

Comment: @brijber no, not if the values do not contain `1`

Comment: this sounds like a range of coin/change related math problems; basically, you'll have to implement an algorithm and try it. At worst case for `n` candidates, a binary exhaustive scan of `n` bits would suffice and be really easy to implement (that's just a `for` loop and a bit-mask), so: if `n` is small, that would be a cheap option. As `n` increases, you'll need better options. You can of course do a full sum first to see if it is even possible.

Comment: You can start by the dumb approach: Generate all possible sums, put them in a list and see if value is in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to get all combinations from the list ant than check if sum is equal to value provided:

Create Extension method to get Combinations from the list of values (this will help you later)

```
public static class ExttensionMethods
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Combinations<T>(this IEnumerable<T> elements, int k)
    {
        return k == 0 ? new[] { new T[0] } :
            elements.SelectMany((e, i) =>
            elements.Skip(i + 1).Combinations(k - 1).Select(c => (new[] { e }).Concat(c)));
    }
}
```

Next create method:

```
public bool CanBeSummed(int value, int[] values)
{
    if (values.Contains(value)) return true;
    var smaller = values.Where(x => x <= value);
    if (!smaller.Any()) return false; // all values are bigger than value
    var count = smaller.Count();
    if (count == 1) return false; // Only 1 number and it is not value since values.Contains(value) has to be false
    // Check all combinations from items (from 2 to x items where x is number of items in smaller list
    return Enumerable.Range(2, count - 1).Any(x => smaller.Combinations(x).Any(c => c.Sum() == value));
}
```

Test:

```
public static object[] SumTest =
{
    new object[] {6, true, new int[] {1, 5, 7, 12, 20}},
    new object[] {37, true, new int[] {1, 5, 7, 12, 20}},
    new object[] {9, false, new int[] {1, 5, 7, 12, 20}}
};

[TestCaseSource("SumTest")]
public void Test(int value, bool expectedResult, int[] values)
{
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, CanBeSummed(value, values));
}
```